# move folder with maven

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I'm trying to use maven to move folder using some regexp to change 1 folder in the path.

My project has multiple packages like :

```
src/main/java/<package1>/<folderToMove>/files.properties    
src/main/java/<package2>/<folderToMove>/files.properties    
src/main/java/<package3>/<folderToMove>/files.properties
```

I need to move those files.properties to the target folder without  in the path like :

```
target/classes/<package1>/files.properties    
target/classes/<package2>/files.properties    
target/classes/<package3>/files.properties
```

I found a solution using maven-resources-plugin but I have to specify manually the source and destination paths, which is not possible due to the number of folders.
I'm looking for a solution using a regex like :

```
<source>(src/main/java)(/.*)(/folderToMove/)(/*properties)</source>
<destination>(target/classes)\2</destination>
```

My regex is probably wrong I just added it to have an exemple of a solution that would work for me.

Is there any maven plugin allowing me to do this, or do I need to add a bash script and call it from maven?

Comment: Property files belong to `src/main/resources` nowhere else.. so simply move those files into the correct location. I don't understand what you are talking about with regex etc. that does not make sense ...

Comment: I'm switching from ant to maven. I can't easily just move files from sources to resources. For the regex, on the ant version, we use a regex to create the new path (without the last folder) when we move those file (the regex is searching for folders with particular name, and gives us the same path without those folders names). I'm trying to do the same think with maven. As we have about 200 folders containing files we need to move, I can't add them all to the pom.xml with maven-resources-plugin.

Comment: Why not? It's the default directory layout...

Comment: I edited the comment with more precisions.

Comment: What is the purpose of those moving and regex handling? Why? Just move those files once to correct location and than it's done... If you migrate you should follow conventions...

Comment: I agree with you about conventions. The problem is that it would be really long, and we can't afford keeping the project failing for a long time. So the purpose would be to quickly fix the test (with a bad solution I agree) and after move gradually all files in the correct folders.